# OS X 10.11.5 Update won't download

Tags: mac-appstore

I am having trouble downloading the OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 Update. Both direct downloads and App Store downloads end up being crazy slow (1kb/sec). Other App Store downloads or the direct iTunes 12.4 download are fast at ~2mb/sec.

I tried flushing the DNS Cache, changing the DNS from Google to ISP, and restarted all systems (Router, Modem, MacBook).

I enabled App Store Debug mode and deleted the App Store Temp Downloads folder but no luck. The download always continues at around 25 MB from the App Store.

I tried direct downloads with Chrome and Safari, but that did not work either. Is there a third party host for the combo update I could try?

Comment: I saw this suggestion on other sites so it's probably worth giving it a try.   Go to `System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced -> DNS` and just add `203.122.233.11`.  If it works I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Or try the combo updater instead - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by downloading the combo update to my server and then downloading the update from there. Apparently my ISP had too much people accessing the direct link from Apple. i don't know. I found it odd. Everything working now tho...